# "," vs "to" in "Merry Christmas eve, everyone!"

Tags: prepositions

Is this technically a correct sentence?

> Merry Christmas eve, everyone!

Or do I need to replace the comma with the word 'to'?

Comment: "Merry Christmas, everyone" or "A Merry Christmas to you all." These are [relatively] fixed expressions, so I wouldn't worry too much about correct grammar. Note that it is "Christmas Eve", not "Christmas eve".

Comment: It's also worth noting that not many people wish a merry Xmas **eve**.  Most wishes are for Xmas day.  But all good wishes are welcome, socially.  The worst that could happen is that you might cause the recipient to stop and think a moment.

Comment: Just a note: As a rule, in the US unless you know that "everyone" is Christian and celebrates Christmas, it would be more proper to say "Happy Holidays" (for example in a workplace, or an online community where these things aren't discussed).

Answer (score 3):

Technically, grammatically, your sentence is correct, and would also be correct if written as "Merry Christmas Eve to everyone!".

The comma version would sound unusual. I've never heard anyone say Merry Christmas Eve. It's not a holiday, just the night(evening, hence eve) before Christmas.

Similar to Mick's comment, it would sound more common to use a variant of the phrase using the word "all", instead of "everyone".

According to wikipedia, it's most common to say "Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_card#International_Christmas_greetings

//Technically, informally, though, it gets confusing because there are several 'correct' ways that it might be expected to be said. Since I'm not clear on your intended usage of the word 'technically' and don't know if you're going to say it in a speech, letter, email, or greeting card, or wherever, it is hard to answer this question precisely. For future holiday reference, you might look up printed Christmas cards to see how they say are written. Hallmark Cards are one of the most widely used card companies in America, and the way they say things would 'sound right' to most people.//